# Nokogiri / bcrypt-ruby error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, bcrypt-ruby

I'm getting the below error when trying to seed my database.  I've included Nokogiri and bcrypt-ruby and haven't specified a version number so they should be fine.

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
rake aborted!
can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Mariogs

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning, (re)install the Nokogiri gem with:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-dir=/usr --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local --with-iconv-dir=/opt/local
```

also check similar questions : [on Linux, how can I resolve WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.0 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396941/how-to-remove-this-warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-8-0-but)

[Mac user and getting WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802410/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-8-but-has-dynamically-lo)