# WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Keep getting below whenever running rspec in sublime text 2. I'm also using guard with spork.:

> WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1

I'm running mavericks if that makes a difference. I'm not sure what this means and have been trying a lot of different stuff but no luck so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802410/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-8-but-has-dynamically-lo)

Comment: I think there's only fixes for mountain lion and lower though. I'm on mavericks so it might be different. I'm going through all the answers there now and nothings working so far...

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  The question linked by carols10cents asks about the dynamically linked version being _older_ than the one nokogiri is built with, while this one is the other way around.  While similar, I believe each has a separate cause.

I have not yet discovered a solution to this problem but will try to post an answer when I find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also was getting this error frequently on OS X 10.9.1. This answer did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658949/1769539

Or, to save you the trip - here's what worked for me, specifically:

"If you installed Nokogiri with bundle install, you can resolve this warning by running `bundle exec gem pristine nokogiri` and then 'bundle install'"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have updated your system libraries after installing the gem, so you have to update nokogiri, to use the current lib version.

```
 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```