# How to fix "uninitialized constant User"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I tried to make a new Devise model "User", but I can't. My server won't load either. I keep getting the error: "uninitialized constant User".

Here's what I tried:

- `bundle install`, `bundle update`, and `gem pristine --all`
- Adding `require 'devise'` into my application.rb
- Restarting my server, which now won't launch
- Running `rails g devise:install` in my terminal

Here's my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem "figaro"
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip' 

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Stack trace:

```
 WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.2
/Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise.rb:289:in `get'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
```

I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: Please share the top few lines of the stacktrace.

Comment: How are you trying to "make a new devise model User"? What happens when you do that?

Comment: I run `rails g devise user` I get the above error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac user and getting WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802410/mac-user-and-getting-warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-8-b)

Comment: @ruby_newbie Good hint. The warning is not part of the question, though, so please don't mark as duplicate.

Comment: I see, so you are getting the error while trying to run `rails g devise User`. Maybe you were a bit too eager with setting devise up? Please try removing all devise related code from your application. Especially the from your `application.rb`. Only keep the entry in the Gemfile. Then try again to run the generator. Does that work?

Comment: There is no need (not in this case, very rarely with other gems) to manually `require 'devise'` anywhere in your code. Rails will take care of this. The error means you havent generated the model. When you generate the model you have to run the migrations. Please red the gem's getting started documentaiton and output of the commands you run. You are missing steps detailed in there.

Comment: @Raffael yup that worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped. Leito also gave good advise in suggesting that you follow the gem's getting started instructions closely.

Answer (score 3):

Have you generated your model?

```
rails generate devise User
```

Comment: That's rather a question than an answer. Please ask for clarifications in comments. This will help the question to get more views. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I did that obviously.

Comment: Can we see user.rb and the related migration?

Comment: @Ursus I can't make the model, that's my problem. I don't have a model or migration.