# Roadie gem causing malloc error: pointer being freed was not allocated in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.7, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831714/nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-7-but-has-dynamically-loaded-2-7)

Getting the following error:

```
ruby(16475,0x12faf6000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f97d2c7002a: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I have tried many things all day to solve this...but it still is coming up and crashing my dev environment.

I figured out that Roadie depends on Nokogiri which depended on another few libraries, one of which possibly contained a bug.

I re installed libxml2, libxslt, libiconv, which in turn led me to reinstall postgresql and recompile ruby.  I uninstalled and reinstalled nokogiri, linking to the libs mentioned in their install guide.

Still getting the malloc error though around the time that Roadie goes into action working on emails.

Also, getting this nokogiri load warning:

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3
```

I uninstalled / reinstalled nokogiri pointing to the right libs, but it may be that another program is loading libXML before nokogiri gets to it, and that this other program was built against the older version? Not too sure...

Any tips on this?

Comment: by the chance - do you run some flavor of debian?

Comment: I'm on osx 10.7.4, using ruby 1.9.3-p194

Comment: anyway, you'd be better of grabbing rvm and installing ruby in it.

Comment: yes, I am using rvm. I also did bundle update, made a new gemfile and reinstalled all gems