# WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this problem on my Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4 config on OSX ML. I do not have this issue on my Arch Linux workstation.

The reason why this warning is so annoying, is that it breaks my Vim plugin (SweetVimRspec), and therefore kills my Vim development workflow, as I cannot test.

I tried every upvoted solution here:
[Mac user and getting WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802410/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-8-but-has-dynamically-lo)

And I cant get rid of it (actually I got rid of it in `nokogiri` itself, but in `rspec and rails console` not at all).

Comment: so...did it build against 2.8.0 and link against 2.7.8? if so what is the location of the 2 libraries?

Comment: I've no idea. How do I find out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452380/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-3-but-has-dynamically-lo ?

Comment: @astropanic nothing worked :(

Comment: find / -iname *libxml* perhaps?

Comment: `nokogiri -v` will tell you the path.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831714/nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-7-but-has-dynamically-loaded-2-7?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I had to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and was getting this warning. I found and tried the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658949/1539589 and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these situations, it works to uninstall all versions of the gem it is complaining about and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of the warning, but it screws up SSH.

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks.

The solution comes from this blog entry:
http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2010/04/24/dynamic-load-paths-in-osx.html